# Change NSTextField Cursor Color When inside TableView Cell

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview, nstablecellview

I have an `NSTextField` that's inside an `NSTableCelView` subclass. I want to change its cursor color because right now the cursor is the same as the background.

Elsewhere in my app, I have changed the cursor color with a handy extension like this:

```
extension NSTextField {
  public func cursorColor(_ cursorColor: NSColor) {
    let fieldEditor = self.window?.fieldEditor(true, for: self) as! NSTextView
    fieldEditor.insertionPointColor = cursorColor
  }
}
```

I put this method inside `viewWillDraw()` in my `NSTableCellView` subclass:

```
override func viewWillDraw() {
  name.cursorColor(NSColor.white)
}
```

... but the app crashes on this line inside the `extension`:

```
let fieldEditor = self.window?.fieldEditor(true, for: self) as! NSTextView //Crash!
```

I assume it's because it can't find a reference to `self.window`, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSWindow.fieldEditor(_: for:)` returns an `NSText?`, yet you're trying to explicitly force-cast it to an `NSTextView`.

So my guess is that either:

1. The returned object is `nil` and your cast is failing or
2. The returned object is a different subclass of `NSText` (and is therefore not an `NSTextView`) and your cast is failing

What's the actual error message you're getting when you crash?

Comment: It looks like `self.window` is `nil` when the `NSTextField` is inside the `NSTableCellView`, but it's never `nil` when it's inside a regular `NSViewController`. The error is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` which, I assume, just means I'm force-unwrapping a nil value.

Comment: It looks like it's just a race condition. If I change it to an `if let` statement and test for the type, it eventually works. The method gets called several times since it's in an `NSTableCellView`, and eventually `self.window` isn't `nil` anymore. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is `viewWillDraw` the right time to set the cursor color?